# How to set scrollView force to bottom when soft keyboard showing?

Tags: android, scrollview, android-softkeyboard

I create one  Edittext to put value and using soft keyboard of android for running it.

This is XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayoutTalking"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_talk"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frlayoutChatBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#f2f2f2" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAddTalk"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_add_talk_activity" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btbKeyboardTalk"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="37dp"
                android:background="@drawable/icon_keyboard" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtinput_talk"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
                android:ems="10"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="14dp" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSendTalk"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_send_talk_activity" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewChating"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/frlayoutChatBar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutOfScrollTalk"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frlayoutIconBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/scrollViewChating"
        android:layout_marginTop="365dp"
        android:background="#f2f2f2" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayoutIconBoxView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="20dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollIconBoxView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Gallery
                    android:id="@+id/horizontallistview"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="-190dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frlayoutButtonUnderIconBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imgbtnReloadIconTalk"
                        android:layout_width="40dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/btn_reload_talk" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And then, I have to touch on EditText twice time, scrollview will move up. But I want touch one time and scrollview will move up.

How I cant do it.

Any help much appreciated! Thanks.